# javascript Boolean() function is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, boolean

Consider the following snippet of code

```
   if(word.startsWith("bool"))
   {
        s = word.split(" ");
        return s+" "+ Boolean(s[1]);
   }
```

Examples

> word ="bool 12>3" ==> true
>
> word ="bool 1>3" ==> false

for queries such as bool 1>2 function says true.
but if I use it in console, it says the correct answer.

Comment: please add `word` and the wanted result.

Comment: `Boolean()` will not evaluate the expression. Any non-empty string is true.

Comment: But I use the same function in console which giving me correct answers

Comment: Did you type a string? `Boolean("1>3")`?

Comment: `1>3` is not the same as `"1>3"`. The console evaluates expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Boolean()` simply performs type conversion, it doesn't evaluate code. When converting a string to boolean, an empty string becomes `false`, a non-empty string becomes `true`.

If you want to evaluate the word, you have to call `eval()`.

```
return s+" "+ Boolean(eval(s[1]));
```

Note that using `eval()` can be dangerous if the data comes from an untrusted source, since this will be able to execute any JavaScript functions.

When you type `Boolean(1>3)` in the console, `1>3` is evaluated as an expression by the console, it's not a string. To see the same problem in the console, enter `Boolean("1>3")`, since `word` is a string, not an expression that has already been evaluated.

Comment: yeah this is working . But why the Boolean is not working in code but working in js console

Comment: I just added an explanation to the answer.